# Query with two ForeignKeys in a model and filter on one of the ForeignKey

Tags: django

I have the three models:

```
class SegmentEffort(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    activity = models.ForeignKey(to=Activity)
    segment = models.ForeignKey(to=Segment)

class Segment(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Activity(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to get all distinct segments from SegmentEffort where SegmentEffort is filtered by Activity belonging to a specific user.

I can get a list of all the segment ids by:

```
sids = SegmentEffort.objects.filter(activity__user=10).order_by('segment_id').values_list('segment_id',
                                                                                                  flat=True).distinct()
```

But I can't get my head around getting distinct a segment queryset... Not enough experience with queries on two ForeignKeys in a model (SegmentEffort).

Thanks for your help, and don't hesitate to ask for clarification id the question is unclear!

Comment: Try this `Segment.objects.filter(segmenteffort__activity__user=user)`

Comment: That looks good! Just add .distinct() and it seems to get what I wanted. Segment.objects.filter(segmenteffort__activity__user=user).distinct()  It's amazing how Django can turn a 4 liner SQL query into a single command! Thank you very much!